# How to fix table header and scrollable Table rows for following Table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have table in HTML format as follows:

```css
th.th {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
th.tl {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <table class="report" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="xbrl-review" rowspan="2"></th>
        <th class="tl custom-border" colspan="1" rowspan="2">
          <div style="width: 200px;"><strong>Document and Entity Information<br></strong>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="xbrl-review"></th>
        <th class="th" colspan="1">3 Months Ended</th>
        <th class="xbrl-review"></th>
        <th class="th" colspan="1"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="xbrl-review"></th>
        <th class="th">
          <div class="xbrl-prop-context">
            <div>
              <div>Sep. 30, 2014</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="xbrl-review"></th>
        <th class="th">
          <div class="xbrl-prop-context">
            <div>
              <div>Nov. 07, 2014</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border ex"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:0em;"><i class="icon-star blue">&#xA0;</i><strong><span class="xbrl-data-text">Document and Entity Information</span></strong></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">&#xA0;</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">&#xA0;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Entity Central Index Key</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">0001501078</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">111111111</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Entity Central Index Key</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">0001501078</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">2222222</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Document Type</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">10-Q</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">3333333</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Document Period End Date</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Sep. 30,
     2014</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">4444444</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Amendment Flag</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">false</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">true</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Current Fiscal Year End Date</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">--06-30</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">4566756</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td valign="top" class="pl custom-border"><a class="a xbrl-prop-element" href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-left:1em;"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Entity Filer Category</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Smaller Reporting Company</span>
        </td>
        <td class="xbrl-review"></td>
        <td class="text xbrl-prop-data custom-border"><span class="xbrl-data-text">Harshal</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Right now `td` content are also moving towards top and below to `th` so it is totally messed up.
My expectation is well formatted Html with fix Table Header(Column Header)  and scrollable Table Rows. Please help me out.

Comment: seems like your second header block is missing a column `<th></th>` that could be your problem. You can use colspan to rectify this.

Comment: nothing is missing this as given input html.

Comment: List out the table headings u need

Comment: @Logeshwaran inside `th` tags Table Headings are there.

Comment: there are 4 headings but the tbody content has only 3 column

Answer (score 1):

you need to avoid using inline styles. Using a separate css style sheet will help make blanket changes for your table. as an example, here is your table with some basic styles.

https://jsfiddle.net/61qktez1/1/

something that helps divide the table rows like this:

```
table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: Sir, still not getting expected output.want table/column Header fixed and  table row scrollable

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I made it for you. I hope you were expecting the same.

```css
.container{
width:400px; 
}
.scroallable_div{
    height: 120px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
     <th width="120px">First</th>
        <th width="120px">Second</th>
 <th width="120px">Third</th>
        <th width="120px">Fourth</th>
        <th width="120px">Fifth</th>
    </tr>
    
    </thead>
</table>
<div class="scroallable_div">
<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="120px"></th>
                <th width="120px"></th>
                <th width="120px"></th>
                <th width="120px"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
                    <td>hgdfgdgfd</td>
            
            </tr>
    
    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: bro this is not because used two table tags also used thead tag I don't want to reformat my html.

Comment: @HarshalBhamare You anyhow have to reformat it because the structure which you have used is improper and without using two tables you might will be able to do it by using Js, but that will increase your code  and decrease your page loading.

Comment: I am ok with js bro.

Comment: For js also you first have to reformat it to basic proper structure. I don't know why you have taken three different heading in three different table head rows.

Comment: bro this is not possible.

Comment: Basic Rule: In any row total number of td should be equal to total number of th in thead unless colspan attribute in used in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129526/discussion-between-sanjay-and-harshal-bhamare).